# Eclipse debug in a wrong file?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm using eclipse and a problem confused me. I downloaded the project from svn and for the first time I tried to do the debug, "ClassNotFoundException" occurred. Even the file is in my project. So I added the file path and then I could do the dubug, BUT instead of the original file, the debug is executed in another file whose icon is a light blue "J".

[image]

As you can see in the image, the left one is the original file, the right one is where the debug is executed. The right icon is light blue. I think it indicate that the file is not in the project.

Now there are two problems, the first one is sometimes the "light blue" code is not the newest. The other problem is I cannot watch the expressions in the file.

[image]

Does anyone know how can I solve these problems? Thank you guys!

Comment: Is it asking for attaching source?

Comment: ["Java file which is not on a build path"](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm) ... so check and correct your _build path_. Check the help page of Eclipse for more information about the build path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be due to build path, check the order of classpath entries , remove the library if you have added original project as a dependency.